# Microservices how database per service handle relations

Tags: database, microservices

So as I understand microservices database per service pattern, if I'm building social networking app

The feed will be in one database and the user will be in another database

So how to handle foreign key relation between user and their post, as any sn I need to return the user data with the post here's the different ways I can think of

First make a user_id field in the post table and in return of the data:
1- the apis make calls to get the data of the user from user apis

Won't it make the service less decoupled?

2- duplicate the user data (the part needed for example first name, last name, avatar and id) and using distributed system like kafka if user changes his data it'll also be changed in the feed database

But won't that just be pointless to have multiple databases?

So how to handle this relation?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you duplicate user data while storing post data depends on what you (or the customer) expects when the user data changes. If they are okay with some delay till the posts data is updated or it not getting updated at all, then it's okay to duplicate user data in posts for efficiency.

But, for microservice design, we need to set aside database schema concerns, and not design from bottom to top (from the data layer to application layer), but from top to bottom (from application layer to data layer). Think of how the customers are going to use the application, and then identify sub-domains within the application domain (called "bounded contexts"), and then proceed to identify the "aggregates" within this bounded context. Refer [aggregates](https://www.jamesmichaelhickey.com/domain-driven-design-aggregates/)

Comment: for example in social networking app, surely they won't like it, but what i think I can do is just make a copy from every user with the required info like first_name..etc and put it in a table in the feed database, it'd be even easier to update, but is that the optimum solution?

Comment: @mohamednaser I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: While the answer is ok and more focus on data replication on events, I think @mohamednaser wanted to know some good practices to retrieve related Users to a list of Posts. Let's say you load 10 Posts, then how you are going to retrieve the User that made each Post? Inside Post Service with request on Auth Service? direct or async HTTP request or Queue with RabbitMQ? Or API Gateway make the Users request and attach them with Posts before sending them back? Or the Client fetch Posts then Users, then any other entities related and combine them in Client Side (which I think is bad for web), etc.